# Fixed Strategy: can it handle protocol errors?

Tags: openlayers

The default strategy for OpenLayers is Fixed. See for example:

http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/sundials.html

```
var sundials = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("KML", {
            projection: map.displayProjection,
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                url: "kml/sundials.kml",
                format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
                    extractStyles: true,
                    extractAttributes: true
                })
            })
        });
```

Is it possible to pass a callback to handle protocol errors?
I can easily do that if I use the low level GET request, for example:

```
var loadkml = function() {
      OpenLayers.Request.GET({
          url: "kml/sundials.kml",
          success: parseData,
          failure: function(req) { alert(req.responseText); }
      });
  }
```

But I don't want to implement a totally new strategy, Fixed is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP` protocol accepts a `callback` options:

`Function to be called when the <read>, <create>, <update>, <delete> or <commit> operation completes`

But the function is never called, bug report: https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/81